# Time delayed execution

Tags: php, time, delay

The (part of) old version of the code looks like this:

```
$oMainsite->checktime(); // In the main program

public function checktime(){
    $timeset = $_SESSION['timeset'];

    if ($_SESSION['timeset'] == ''){
        $_SESSION['timeset'] = date('H:i', strtotime("+5   min"));
    } else { 
        $timeset = $_SESSION['timeset'];
    }

    $arr_tijd = getdate();
    $uren = $arr_tijd["hours"];

    if ($uren < 10){
        $uren = 0; $uren .= $arr_tijd["hours"];
    }

    $minuten .= $arr_tijd["minutes"];

    if ($minuten < 10){
        $minuten = 0; $minuten .= $arr_tijd["minutes"];
    }

    $tijd = $uren;
    $tijd .= ":";
    $tijd .= $minuten;

    if($timeset <= $tijd){
        generate_question();
    }
}
```

Part of the function generate question() looks like:

```
........
$timedelay = rand(3,10);  
$_SESSION['timeset'] = date('H:i', strtotime("+".$timedelay." min"));
.........
// Display question
```

In the main program the function checktime() only executes when the page is refreshed. But if there is no user input the site stays idle, which resolves in the fact that the checktime() and also the 'Generate_question()' function never executes.

Is there a way to execute Checktime() even if the site is idle? Or do I have to approach this differently?

Comment: Sounds like a [cron job](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/) problem.

Comment: Make use of `setinterval` on JS and load your PHP file (ofcourse with the function inside it).

Comment: In the future... and for the sanity of everyone, please pick **just one** spoken language for your naming conventions. Either Dutch or English, don't mix in both...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to execute Checktime() even if the site is idle? Or do I have to approach this differently?

Yes, there's well known techniques for this. Mike in the comments has suggested you use a **cron job**. He should have posted it as an answer since the link is more informative than my post.

On Linux/BSD cron is a program that runs at a pre-defined interval, you can specify a task to run once a year, every minute, or just on thursdays every 4 hours, etc...

On Windows systems you'll likely control that as a scheduled task, but I'm not an expert with Windows servers.

On Mainframes you either know what you're doing or shouldn't even touch that system.

Answer (score 0):

How simpel it can be if you write it down on a forum :-)

To make the page reload or refresh itself, we have to use the following code inside the head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" >
```

The attribute http-equiv="refresh" calls for refresh of the page.

The attribute content="5" sets the time for refresh.

The time after which the page has to reload is set using the content attribute. 
Say if you want the page to refresh after 10 seconds interval, set content value to 10.

We would recommend the time of refresh [reloading interval] be above 5 seconds. This is because you have to consider the page loading time.

Thank you all for youre contributions.

Comment: WRONG :-) This does not complete do the job. It cleares also the <form> on the site. And that is ofcourse not suppost to happen.